# Avoid duplicate result Multithread Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to make my actual crawler Multithread.
When I set the Multithread, several instance of the function will be started.

**Exemple :**

If my function I use `print range(5)` and I will have `1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5` if I have 2 Thread.

How can can I have the result `1,2,3,4,5` in Multithread ?

My actual code is a crawler as you can see under :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=" + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'question-hyperlink'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            title = link.string
            print(title)
            get_single_item_data("http://stackoverflow.com/" + href)
        page += 1

def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    res = soup.find('span', {'class': 'vote-count-post '})
    print("UpVote : " + res.string)

trade_spider(1)
```

How can I call `trade_spider()` in Multithread without duplicate link ?

Comment: Have you tried using a [shared `multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)?

Comment: Not yet, I will tried

Comment: @DavidCullen Can you give me an exemple please, I don't understant how the shared multiprocessing works in the docs. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the page number be an argument to the `trade_spider` function.

Call the function in each process with a different page number so that each thread gets a unique page.

For example:

```
import multiprocessing

def trade_spider(page):
    url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=%s" % (page,)
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'question-hyperlink'}):
        href = link.get('href')
        title = link.string
        print(title)
        get_single_item_data("http://stackoverflow.com/" + href)

# Pool of 10 processes
max_pages = 100
num_pages = range(1, max_pages)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
# Run and wait for completion.
# pool.map returns results from the trade_spider
# function call but that returns nothing
# so ignoring it
pool.map(trade_spider, num_pages)
```

Comment: Can I have an example please.

Comment: Updated with example

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time

max_pages = 100
shared_page = Value('i', 1)
arg_list = (max_pages, shared_page)
process_list = list()
for x in range(2):
    spider_process = Process(target=trade_spider, args=arg_list)
    spider_process.daemon = True
    spider_process.start()
    process_list.append(spider_process)
for spider_process in process_list:
    while spider_process.is_alive():
        time.sleep(1.0)
    spider_process.join()
```

Change the parameter list of `trade_spider` to

```
def trade_spider(max_pages, page)
```

and remove the

```
    page = 1
```

This will create two processes that will work through the page list by sharing the `page` value.